# User profile creation time for the profiles created today is not showing anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tooltips, timestamps

On user profile pages, the relative timestamp such as

> Member for 2 days

has exact date and time of profile creation, available on hover:

```
<span title="2017-10-28 20:35:56Z">2 days</span>
```

But if the profile was created today, this information is not available:

> Member since today

(No title attribute here). This was the case with profiles created today too, but somehow got removed. Can this please be fixed?

Time of creation is most relevant for accounts created today, e.g., a wave of spam accounts.

Comment: [Bug confirmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWSqz.png) - there is a tooltip on Area51 which proves this was the original design.

Comment: Feel free to roll back if you think I removed too much, I just believe bug report will get faster attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the next build, "member since today" will have the creation timestamp like the older profiles do.

(Note that the whole phrase will be inside the span rather than just "today". The reason being that I don't want to add complexity to existing text translations for a fairly minor case.)